# SQL Server Looking to return random 10% of records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table on my SQL server that I need to pull back a random 10% of the records based for each user and date.  Below illustrates the idea with the yellow Column being the calc that I am trying to figure out.

I reviewed the other questions and they dont appear to answer my question.

[image]

Comment: @Joe . . . Assigning a flag is different from filtering the rows.  Which do you want?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  either will work for me